# How To Prevent Direct Url Access In Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Let's said I have 2 pages "LowAdmin" and "Login"

I want to prevent user from accesing "LowAdmin" directly from url.
Instead, I want to redirect them to "Login" page.

I have a problem explaining my pages to my teacher, because he access LowAdmin, instead of Login page.

Anyone can help? I almost finish this final project.

Comment: Use session to redirect. First check whether a session is set or not, if not then redirect. Do you know how to use sessions in CodeIgniter.

Comment: @GeordyJames I have set session for my login page, but it use database like username and password, is there a way to make session without it? Because I don't know

Comment: Bro you need session redirect in LowAdmin Controller constructor like this if(empty($_SESSION['adminuser'])) 
    {
    redirect('login');
    }

Comment: Post your two controllers codes I will modify it if you need help

Comment: I don't even know how to post codes here LOL but you can check it at my github project [link]https://github.com/HermesED/Project_UKM_K-ART. Check my controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By analysing your project code in GitHub you can redirect by changing your constructor function of LowAdmin Controller like this.

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();      

     $loginstatus   = $this->session->userdata('status');
          if($loginstatus!="login2"){
          redirect(base_url("login"));
     }

    $this->load->model('project_model');           
}
```

Please comment below if you encountered any problem.

Comment: Great. If my code works then flag it as answer to this question so that everybody with similar problems can try this method

Answer (score 0):

By session you can
 do it.
For example

```
public function index()
{ 
          $this->load->library('session');
          $admindata   = $this->session->userdata('admin');
              if($admindata){

             $this->load->view('admin/dashboard');
                             }else{
             redirect('admin/login');
                             }
}
```